# Rename Sftp file issue

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

i am trying to rename a XML file using **Renci.SshNet.Sftp** RenameFile function but its keeping giving me an exception "File not found". 
Here is the code :

```
    public bool renameFile(String strOldPathName, String strNewPathName)
    {
        bool blResult = false;

        try
        {
            this.m_strErrorDes = "";
            this.m_sftpClient.RenameFile(strOldPathName, strNewPathName);
            blResult = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            this.m_strErrorDes = "SFTP_0005: ERROR - " + exp.Message;
        }
        return blResult;
    }
```

The function above is called from here :

```
foreach (SftpFile sFile in ienFileList){
    ..
    .. 
    ..
    string NewName = sFile.FullName.Substring(0, sFile.FullName.Length - 4) + "Done.xml";
    this.renameFile(sFile.FullName, NewName);
}
```

I also tried to change the SftpClient.WorkingDirectory path but it seems its not working

The file FullName is "/test/myXml.xml" and the newName is "/test/myXmlDone.xml". 
I really do not get why it does notfind the file after i gave him the full path.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists on the remote and you have write permission to the `/test` directory and `/test/myXml.xml` file?

Comment: Yep i am sure. i success to download file and upload. but something went wrong with the rename

Comment: Show us exact exception error message including callstack + Can you rename the file using any standalone SFTP client? (e.g. WinSCP) Show us its log file.

Comment: The exact message error is : exp = {"File not found"} ; the Call stack is : > AttNightUpdateService.exe!AttNightUpdateService.SftpProtocol.renameFile(string strOldPathName, string strNewPathName) Line 146 C#
  AttNightUpdateService.exe!AttNightUpdateService.SftpProtocol.listFile(string strSftpPath) Line 243 C#
  AttNightUpdateService.exe!AttNightUpdateService.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 32 C#
  [External Code]

Comment: and i can rename the file using Filezila or WinSCP . i doesn't manage to find the log file

Comment: Callstack of the exception, please. What you have posted in probably a callstack of a breakpoint in your `catch` clause.

Comment: How hard it can be to find WinSCP or FileZilla logging preferences? First hit in google: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging

Comment: is that what you mean of exp Callstack ? :    at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestRename(String oldPath, String newPath)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.RenameFile(String oldPath, String newPath, Boolean isPosix)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.RenameFile(String oldPath, String newPath)
   at AttNightUpdateService.SftpProtocol.renameFile(String strOldPathName, String strNewPathName) in C:\HilanUpdatesService\AttNightUpdateService\SftpProtocol.cs:line 142

Comment: Yes, thanks. What about the log file?

Comment: . 2018-09-13 10:11:18.136 Renaming file "myXmlFile.xml" to "myXml.xml".
> 2018-09-13 10:11:18.136 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 47, Number: 3858
< 2018-09-13 10:11:18.138 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 21, Number: 3588
. 2018-09-13 10:11:18.138 Discarding reserved response
< 2018-09-13 10:11:18.250 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 21, Number: 3858
< 2018-09-13 10:11:18.250 Status code: 0
. 2018-09-13 10:11:18.250 Listing directory "/test".

Comment: this is the log file , is that fine ? thanks !

Comment: And if you call simple `this.m_sftpClient.RenameFile("/test/myXmlFile.xml", "/test/myXml.xml");`? (making sure `myXmlFile.xml` exists before you call that).

Comment: edit : working !! but why ?

Comment: I look at the function and the arguments it get from sFile.FullName are the same

Comment: Post [mcve] showing how your code fails and `this.m_sftpClient.RenameFile("/test/myXmlFile.xml", "/test/myXml.xml");` succeeds right after it.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to figure it out